# Stopping forwarding a dynamic port mid session

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

When connecting to a server, I can open a port forward midway though by

```
Enter
~C
-D 8080
```

When it comes to closing that forward though im a bit lost

The docs say

> It also allows the cancellation of existing remote port-forwardings
>                using -KR hostport.

But when trying that the forward survives. Trying -KD and -KL with port 8080 also dont kill it.

What is the best way to stop a forward mid session ?

Comment: I just tested this and this is not my experience. A forward started with `-D 8080` was killed with `-KD 8080`.

Comment: ssh> -D 8080
Forwarding port.

ssh> -KD 8080
Not supported.
  is what i get

Comment: What version are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to be using an out-of-date version of OpenSSH. Cancellation of local/dynamic forwardings was added in 6.0.

> What's new in OpenSSH 6.0:
>   April 23rd, 2012
>
> Features:
>   ...
>   - ssh(1): support for cancelling local and remote port forwards via the multiplex socket. Use ssh -O cancel -L xx:xx:xx -R yy:yy:yy user@host" to request the cancellation of the specified forwardings
>   - support cancellation of local/dynamic forwardings from ~C commandline

Comment: Im using xubuntu 12.04 LTS. The latest version there is 5.91. Just did a manual upgrade and now it seems to be working. Thanks !